Do we need induction to prove linear independence?
Let $n\geq 2$ be a natural number, and $K$ a field. Let $U$ be the following subvectorspace of $K^n$.
$U=\{(x_1,\dotso, x_n)\in K^n: x_1+\dotso +x_n=0\}$.
The task is to show that $e_1=(1,-1,0,\dotso, 0), e_2=(0,1,-1,0,\dotso, 0), \dotso, e_{n-1}=(0,\dotso,0,1,-1)$ is a basis of $U$.
In my opinion we do not need induction to prove that these vectors are linearly independent. Is that correct, or is induction inevitable?
Thanks.

Well, have you got a non-inductive proof?  That would settle the matter...

How do you work (rigorously) with $\dots$?

I think so. We can just write down $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_ie_i=0$ calculate that sum, and solve the system of equations. That would be my approach.

@TedShifrin: I do not. My claim is that my calculation just works independend of $n$. So I do not see the need for induction.

@TedShifrin Basically it is my question if you can avoid induction or you have to prove this statement by induction.

As far as I can tell, your argument is a handwave that would be acceptable to a first-year student, but not in a later, more advanced, rigorous mathematics course.

What exactly is handwavy about it? Without writing down detals, but when I just calculate the sum stated in a comment above and do the calculation, I can show that all the coefficients have to be $0$. That calculation just generalizes for every $n$. Does it not?

I don't see how you can write down an explicit calculation without knowing a particular value of $n$. Otherwise, it sounds like an induction argument with the details omitted. But feel free to edit your post with the explicit proof. Remember that any argument with $\dots$ in it is an implicit inductive argument.

I think I see your point now, and I agree. It still seems odd to me to prove this inductively. It does not feel like a "real" inductive argument.

Does your proof of the linear independence of eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues "feel" like an inductive argument?

No, it does not. :)

I try an inductive proof now. I struggle to apply the inductive hypothesus. The induction is by the dimension. How do I pass from vectors of length $n+1$ to vectors of length $n$ to apply the hypothesus?

@TedShifrin I think I see it now. I do not apply induction on the dimension but on the length of the list of vectors and I claim that the $e_i$ stay linearly independent. Then I can extend this list to a basis of the $U$ and show that this missing vector can be choosen of the form $(0,\dotso, 0, 1,-1)$.

My freshman number theory professor had a pithy explanation of induction: "Et cetera is permissible". Hopefully I took this the correct way: et cetera is permissible because you can usually translate it into an induction proof. So, I'll say that ... proofs [that is, "dot dot dot proofs"] are permissible because you can usually translate them into an induction proof. In neither case does that make the induction proof unnecessary.

You don't need inducción (at least not its full power), note that $e_i=e_i' - e_{i+1}'$ for all $i=1,\dots, n-1$, where $\{e_1', \dots, e_n'\}$ is the canonical basis of $K^n$.
Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i e_i=0$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(\lambda_i e_i' -\lambda_i e_{i+1}') =0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i e_i' - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i e_{i+1}' =0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i e_i' - \sum_{i=2}^{n}\lambda_{i-1} e_{i}' =0$$
$$\lambda_1e_1' + \sum_{i=2}^{n-1}(\lambda_i-\lambda_{i-1}) e_i' - \lambda_{n-1}e_{n}'=0$$
Since $\{e_1', \dots, e_n'\}$ is l.i then $\lambda_1, \lambda_{n-1}=0$ and $\lambda_i - \lambda_{i-1} =0$ for all $i=2, \dots, n-1$, from this is easy to see that $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_{n-1}=0$ and you can use a similar argument to prove that $\{e_1, \dots, e_{n-1}\}$ generates $U$.
At the end, it's "obvious" from $\lambda_1, \lambda_{n-1}=0$ and $\lambda_i = \lambda_{i-1}$ that $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_{n-1}=0$ but if we wanted to be totally formal we have to proceed with an inductive argument, rather than using the principle of induction is better to use a relaxed version, called the principle of finite induction, that is just induction but over a finite set.
